# Input reads are 55 million but only 1 million were used for alignment

Tags: bioinformatics

[U]I ran this code using tophat (v2.1.0) to align reads (bowtie2 (v2.2.6.0)) from my RNA-seq fastq file using the bowtie2 genomes.bt2 indexes from igenomes (Homo_sapiens_UCSC_hg19)([/U]:

```
tophat2 -p 8 -G /home/ajsn6c/Desktop/Kumar_RNA-seq/Homo_sapiens_UCSC_hg19 /Homo_sapiens/UCSC/hg19/Sequence/Bowtie2Index/hg19.gtf /home/ajsn6c/Desktop/Kumar_RNA-seq/Homo_sapiens_UCSC_hg19/Homo_sapiens/UCSC/hg19/Sequence/Bowtie2Index/genome HPDE_S11_L002_R1_001.fastq
```

[U]My fastq file is around 13 GB. However, after alignment my accepted hits file is only 50 MB.[/U]

[U]Heres the alignment output saying I have around 55 million kept reads:[/U]

### [2018-02-21 13:58:33]     Beginning TopHat run (v2.1.0)

```
[2018-02-21 13:58:33]     Checking for Bowtie
      Bowtie version:    2.2.6.0
[2018-02-21 13:58:33] Checking for Bowtie index files (genome)..
[2018-02-21 13:58:33] Checking for reference FASTA file
[2018-02-21 13:58:33] Generating SAM header for /home/ajsn6c/Desktop /Kumar_RNA-seq/Homo_sapiens_UCSC_hg19/Homo_sapiens/UCSC/hg19/Sequence/Bowtie2Index/genome
[2018-02-21 13:58:35] Reading known junctions from GTF file
[2018-02-21 13:58:39] Preparing reads
 left reads: min. length=12, max. length=101, 55970267 kept reads (45104 discarded)
Warning: short reads (<20bp) will make TopHat quite slow and take large amount of memory because they are likely to be mapped in too many places
[2018-02-21 14:17:45] Building transcriptome data files Panc1/tmp/genes
[2018-02-21 14:17:59] Building Bowtie index from genes.fa
[2018-02-21 14:32:14] Mapping left_kept_reads to transcriptome genes with Bowtie2 
[2018-02-21 15:38:44] Resuming TopHat pipeline with unmapped reads
[2018-02-21 15:38:44] Mapping left_kept_reads.m2g_um to genome genome with Bowtie2 
[2018-02-21 16:17:07] Mapping left_kept_reads.m2g_um_seg1 to genome genome with Bowtie2 (1/4)
[2018-02-21 16:18:13] Mapping left_kept_reads.m2g_um_seg2 to genome genome with Bowtie2 (2/4)
[2018-02-21 16:19:32] Mapping left_kept_reads.m2g_um_seg3 to genome genome with Bowtie2 (3/4)
[2018-02-21 16:20:46] Mapping left_kept_reads.m2g_um_seg4 to genome genome with Bowtie2 (4/4)
[2018-02-21 16:21:59] Searching for junctions via segment mapping
[2018-02-21 16:25:24] Retrieving sequences for splices
[2018-02-21 16:27:18] Indexing splices
Building a SMALL index
[2018-02-21 16:27:37] Mapping left_kept_reads.m2g_um_seg1 to genome segment_juncs with Bowtie2 (1/4)
[2018-02-21 16:27:50] Mapping left_kept_reads.m2g_um_seg2 to genome segment_juncs with Bowtie2 (2/4)
[2018-02-21 16:28:03] Mapping left_kept_reads.m2g_um_seg3 to genome segment_juncs with Bowtie2 (3/4)
[2018-02-21 16:28:17] Mapping left_kept_reads.m2g_um_seg4 to genome segment_juncs with Bowtie2 (4/4)
[2018-02-21 16:28:31] Joining segment hits
[2018-02-21 16:31:02] Reporting output tracks

[2018-02-22 19:21:42] A summary of the alignment counts can be found in ./tophat_out/align_summary.txt
[2018-02-22 19:21:42] Run complete: 02:08:37 elapse
```

[U]This is the alignment summary from the align_summary files[/U]:

```
reads:
      Input     :    926337
       Mapped   :    898584 (97.0% of input)
        of these:     14621 ( 1.6%) have multiple alignments (14 have >20)
```

97.0% overall read mapping rate.

Why is the input only 900K, when it kept 55 million reads? The quality of the reads have excellent phred scores too. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 0):

These entries in your log file are odd:

> [2018-02-21 14:17:45] Building transcriptome data files Panc1/tmp/genes
>
> [2018-02-21 14:17:59] Building Bowtie index from genes.fa

Here is your `tophat2` command (I have restructured the command to help with readability)

```
./tophat2 \
    -p 8 \
    -G /home/ajsn6c/Desktop/Kumar_RNA-seq/Homo_sapiens_UCSC_hg19 /Homo_sapiens/UCSC/hg19/Sequence/Bowtie2Index/hg19.gtf \
    /home/ajsn6c/Desktop/Kumar_RNA-seq/Homo_sapiens_UCSC_hg19/Homo_sapiens/UCSC/hg19/Sequence/Bowtie2Index/genome \
    HPDE_S11_L002_R1_001.fastq
```

1. There seem to be some erroneous whitespaces (e.g. `[...]Homo_sapiens_UCSC_hg19 /Homo_sapiens[...]`; not sure if that is the issue.
2. Based on your command the transcriptome should be build based on file `[...]/UCSC/hg19/Sequence/Bowtie2Index/hg19.gtf`; I have no idea where `Panc1/tmp/genes` is coming from, but clearly this file is being used to build a reference transcriptome, and not `[...]/hg19.gtf`.

Comment: I designated Panc1 as the output folder, then it creates a tmp (temporary) folder where it produces hg19.bt2 files and a fasta file then goes away. The run also takes 2 hours. It should be longer right? I'll post more logs and examples later. Thanks for your response!

Comment: But your `tophat2` command does not contain any reference to `Panc1`; so from where does `tophat2` pick up `Panc1`? I've checked one of my recent `tophat2` runs, and alignment of 40 million PE reads took close to 5 hours.

Comment: One more thing I realised: Your FASTQ filename suggests that you have PE reads; but in your `tophat2` command you only seem to use one of the read pairs (`R1`); that seems odd.